# Calculating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Xn\log(1+\frac{|f|^2}{n^2})\,dm$, where $m$ is a measure on a measurable space $X$, and $f\in L^1(m)$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $m$ be a measure on a measurable space $X$ and $f\in L^1(m)$.

How can we calculate: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Xn\cdot\log\left(1+\frac{|f|^2}{n^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}m$$
My first thought was to use the DCT for the sequence $f_n(x)= \frac{1}{n}\cdot\log\left(1+\frac{|f(x)|^2}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}$. We can easily prove that $|f_n|$ is bounded by $|f|^2$ but I cannot show that $|f|^2$ is integrable. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `\log`. In general, standard functions and reasonable acronyms can be accessed in MathJax via a backslash

Comment: You won't be able to show $|f|^2$ is integrable because it's not true in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\ln (1+x)=2\ln (\sqrt {1+x})\leq 2 \ln (1+\sqrt x)\leq 2\sqrt x$. Can you finish?

Comment: So, if I'm correct the final answer is $0$?

Comment: @MarsPi Yes, that is correct.